# Solidity Parser Error on Remix - Cook Function

Tags: function, ethereum, solidity, action, remix

**UPDATE** - Solved!

```
function cook(
    uint8[11] calldata actions,
    uint8[4] calldata actions,
    uint8[30] calldata actions,
    uint8[2] calldata actions,
    uint8[4] calldata actions,
    uint8[21] calldata actions,
    uint256[] calldata values,
    bytes[] calldata datas
)
```

---

Using Solidity on the Remix platform, I'm trying to implement the Cook function (5 transactions as one transaction) but I am getting the following Parser Error:
**Expected ',' but got '='**
(The '=' after the word 'actions' on line 5 is apparently wrong)
The error is on line 5 of this code:

```
function cook(
    uint8[] calldata actions,
    uint256[] calldata values,
    bytes[] calldata datas,
    actions=[11,4,30,2,4,21], values=[0,0,0,0,0,0], datas=[ '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000', '0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a838b72544589fe19ad000000000000000000000000ff498bbcbf40d0f30f178f553e8fa36153baf30b', '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', '0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ae1c9e401d6eba9d98d0000000000000000000000007f621538fdd1621dd0405d6991b4cae2694be6480000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000', '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020bf419454384f012020000000000000000000000007f621538fdd1621dd0405d6991b4cae2694be648', '0x000000000000000000000000a47c8bf37f92abed4a126bda807a7b7498661acd0000000000000000000000007f621538fdd1621dd0405d6991b4cae2694be648000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020bf419454384f01202']) => (value1=10062861030000000027939, value2=9665236316526063129090)
)
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think there is a number of things wrong here with the way you are trying to implement this.  First you can't assign values like that in the function arguments, this needs to be done in the body of your function.  Secondly I see that you're trying to use an arrow function, and I don't believe there is such a thing in Solidity.  You will want to follow standard Solidity syntax for these types of things.  They won't directly correlate with JS

Comment: Thanks Michael! I just edited my post realizing the errors I made. Please have a look. What did you mean by the 'arrow function'?

Comment: you're trying to execute the function by doing ```=> (value1=10062861030000000027939, value2=9665236316526063129090)``` which is an arrow function that I believe is only exclusive to JS and not Solidity.  Also, I don't believe you can have multiple arguments with the same name in your function declaration either.

Comment: Yes. I mistakenly used an event log and I thought it was code. Corrected. Thanks Michael